# Increment variable defined inside inner for loop without affect of outter for loop

Tags: python, algorithm

```
In [6]: for i in range(0, 3):
    print(i)
    for k, v in test.items():
        hee = 5
        if key == 'test1':
            hee = hee + 5
            print(hee)
   ...:
0
10
10
1
10
10
2
10
10
```

I expect the result below:

```
0
10
10
1
15
15
2
20
20
```

Is there any way to get this output using similar code as above: two for-loops but inner for-loop have variable which is incremented each time irrespective of outer loop?

Comment: First set `hee = 5` outside the loop and then just don't reset it to `hee = 5` inside the loop.

Comment: put `hee` outside the first loop. Also, since you decided to post a question, please provide code that can run: use `k` instead of `key` because you're giving us a `NameError` and supply values for `test` or that's another `NameError` too. You're asking for help, at least be willing enough to put effort in the question.

Comment: How it is python 2.7 and python 3 both problem?

Answer (score 0):

Below code should do the job. I have added comments for explanation.

```
test = {'sna':[10,20,30], 'dna':[100,200,300]}

# create a temporary variable to store initial value of hee which is 5
temp = 5
for i in range(0, 3):
    print(i)
    for k, v in test.items():
        # set hee to temp
        hee = temp
        if k == 'sna':
            hee = hee + 5
            temp = hee
            print(hee)
            print(hee)
            # you might want to use break statement since each key is unique in dictionary
            # once you find key, there is no need to iterate through the dictionary
            break
```

Output:

```
0
10
10
1
15
15
2
20
20
```

Comment: below code still giving the same result.                                                   In [19]: for i in range(0,3):
    print(i)
    for k,v in test.items():
        hee= temp
        if k == 'test1':
            hee = hee + 5
            print(hee)
            break
   ....:
0
10
1
10
2
10

Comment: Can you mention what is present in test dictionary?

Comment: you can consider test dictionary here as - test = {'sna':[10,20,30], 'dna':[100,200,300]}

Comment: @ChetanJain based on your comment, I have updated the answer.